# why call suggestDesiredDimensions method in a new thread other than call it directly

Tags: android

```
new Thread("setWallpaperDimension") {
    public void run() {
        mWallpaperManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(mWallpaperWidth, mWallpaperHeight);
    }
}.start();
```

The code above i saw it in launcher2's source code, what i want know is why #suggestDesiredDimensions method gets called in a new thread, can i call it directly without starting a new thread?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can, only the other way around might cause trouble (calling ui-thread-only functions from non-ui threads).

But of course, it might have performance reasons why this is called in a new thread. It might be triggering some recalculations and stuff that might affect your UI responsiveness...